# Не выводит в консоль больше строки кириллического текста

Tags: windows-7, cmd, c++

Подключен файл `<windows.h>` и установлены следующие настройки кодировки для консоли:

```
 SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Кодировка файлов utf-8.

```
cout << "\nРеализация списка на базе
массива указателей \n\n"
          << "  Выберите операцию:\n";
```

В консоль выводит только **Реализация списка на базе массива указателей**

Comment: А без SetConsoleCP() и SetConsoleOutputCP() выводит обе строки (только "кракозябры" д.б. быть)?

Comment: @avp, именно

Comment: Действительно, после CP_UTF8 в моей винде вывод русских букв в консоли, **причем через cout << ** тоже отваливается.

А вот тривиальный *puts()* продолжает выводить.

Проверял g++.

--

Загадка. +1 к вопросу.

@Jeremen1, короче, бросайте винду (или по крайней мере кресты (чисто Сишный вывод-то работает...)).

Comment: А что за консоль то? Стандартный Windows или там какой-нить VT* терминал?

Comment: Я пробовал в стандартной консоли (которая через run cmd запускается).

В emacs eshell эмуляторе терминала все нормально работает.

Винда 32-бит XP SP3.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, должно быть `\r\n` вместо `\n`.

А вообще, лучше, наверное, так:

```
cout << endl << "Реализация списка на базе массива указателей" << endl << endl << "Выберите операцию:" << endl;
```

Comment: не помогло(